# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de trabajar con ramas en git?

Tags: git, git-push

Actualmente en mi proyecto tengo dos ramas ‘**master**’ y ‘**mi-rama**’.

El objetivo es trabajar con ‘mi-rama’ para no liarla en ‘master’, no obstante, nunca he trabajado con ramas antes (siempre directamente con master).

Para mantener actualizado mi repositorio, **¿qué se supone que debería hacer?**

**Opción A)** ¿Cambiarme a la rama master con `checkout` y hacer un pull mientras sigo trabajando con ‘mi-rama’?

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout mi-rama
```

**Opción B)** ¿Hacer un `pull` directamente en ‘mi-rama’ para bajarme los cambios, cambiarle a ‘master’ y hacer otro `pull`?

```
git pull
git checkout master
git pull
```

**Opción C)** ¿Cambiarme a ‘master’, hacer un `merge` para aplicar mis cambios, eliminar ‘mi-rama’, hacer un `pull` (en master) para bajarme los cambios y luego si quiero añadir algo más, volver a crear otra rama (clon de un ‘master‘ actualizado)?

Si los pasos que debo seguir no corresponden con ninguna de esas opciones, apreciaría que me lo hagan saber, en caso contrario, ¿cuál de esas opciones es la correcta?

Por otro lado, ¿es mejor hacer `merge` con ‘master‘ para luego hacer `push` de mis cambios al servidor o puedo hacer directamente `push` con ‘mi-rama’? (Actualmente estoy trabajando con ‘mi-rama’ solamente en local).

Comment: Lo que yo haría es: `git pull origin master` para bajarme los cambios de master _remoto_ (no entiendo por qué la gente utiliza una rama como `master` en local para tener que estarla manteniendo a la par de la remota). Según la configuración que hagas de `pull.rebase`, eso podría hacer un `merge` o un `rebase` (y lo que sea mejor depende de si esa rama la va a usar más gente o si es solo un feature). https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase

Comment: Por cierto, comentario general: esta no es _la forma correcta de trabajar con ramas en git_. Eso es solo una forma _recurrente_ de trabajo en git.... y no tanto en git, sino con los proveedores como gitlab o github. En realidad es git _demasiado_ flexible en cuanto a lo que te deja hacer con las ramas. Lo importante al respecto es saber que **las ramas son solo apuntadores a commits** (eso te va a despejar bastantes dudas en el futuro, una vez que lo asimiles). Y hay cosas que _no_ se debe hacer como un rebase de una rama que esté usando más gente.

Comment: Existen los que se llaman *Flujos de trabajo* de Git: Son distintas formas de usar Git según tus gustos y necesidades. No hay una que sea mejor que otra porque es algo opinable. Por eso voto por cerrar esta pregunta, pero aporto este enlace donde explica lo básico: https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Comment: Yo utilizo Develop como rama "cuasi-principal", ahi me paro, hago pull, creo una rama nueva para una tarea particular con ``git checkout -b rama``, y acá trabajo. Cuando termino de trabajar en esta nueva rama, vuelvo a hacer pull origin develop por si alguien subio cambios a develop, y finalmente los subo. Si esta todo bien, mergeo con develop y elimino la rama de la tarea. Cada tanto, develop se mergea con Master, que es la rama que esta enlazada a Vercel o similar.

Comment: voy a ser sincero, la pregunta esta fuera de tema, tu pregunta no tiene que ver con programacion, si no que con controles de versiones ... incluso como herramienta de desarrollo ... tampoco esta asociada a ser resuelta con programacion ... te doy el credito por ser buena pregunta y que todo desarrollador debe conocer. saludos.

Comment: en segundo punto ... estoy seguro que lo ideal de trabajar con ramas es por que tendras un equipo colaborativo de desarrollo ... dependiendo de como son las interacciones puedes A.) rama por usuario B.) rama por feature. aconcejo la ultima. y siempre trabajar en la rama especifica para cada cosa... principio de `SOLID.`

Comment: Las respuestas han sido buenas y no quiero ser yo el que elija la mejor, voten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes tus cambios listos en tu branch, una opción es:

1. Hacer checkout a master local, y luego un git pull para traerte los posibles cambios de la rama master remota
2. Hacer un checkout a tu branch
3. Hacer un git rebase de la forma: `git rebase -i master`, resolver el archivo que tiene el plan del rebase
4. Push de tu rama local hacia el repositorio remoto, `git push -f origin <tu rama>`
5. Lanzar un PR en github o gitlab o lo que sea, para pedir que esa rama remota se le haga merge a tu master remoto
6. Aprovar el PR y el merge directamente desde la interfaz de gitlab, o github o lo que sea

Esto en el caso que estes trabajando en un proyecto con varios y tu rama master esté marcada como protegida (no le puedes hacer push).

La forma más fácil que considero es dejando tu rama principal (main/master) desprotegida y luego:

1. git switch master
2. git pull origin master
3. git merge "mi-feature"
4. git push origin master

Respecto a tu pregunta de si puedes hacer un push directo a master: si puedes.

Primero la rama remota tiene que dejar de estar protegida, y luego:

1. `git push origin mi-rama:master`

O generalizando: `git push <remote> <local branch>:<remote branch>`

Pero hay varios asuntillos en esta aproximación. Uno es que te puedes equivocar y poner, `git push origin :master`, osea, sin la branch local antes de los dos puntos, y esto eliminaría tu rama master.

La otra es que ahora tu rama local de master quedaría desfasada.

Respecto a si un flujo de trabajo es mejor o peor, pues no hay "mejor" en términos absolutos. Depende de muchos factores:

- Tipo de proyecto en el que estás
- Tipo (tamaño y roles) del equipo en el que estás

Hay muchos tipos de formas de trabajar con GIT workflows.

### Git-flow

Por ejemplo, la más conocida (y al parecer medio obsoleta y conflictiva) es "**Git flow**", que, hasta donde entiendo, se basa en el trabajo con ramas que tienen mucho tiempo de duración (semanas, meses):

- La rama estable es "main" o "master"
- La rama de la entrega se llama "dev" o "develop" o "development", y en esta rama se integran los nuevos cambios o "features"
- Las features se obtienen de hacer un fork de development
- Estas nuevas ramas son llamadas "feature branch"

[image]

Los pros con esta manera de trabajar (workflow) es que tiene gran estabilidad, te permite hacer pruebas sobre una gran implementación de features que pueden trabajar juntas y sobre esta rama "develop" o de desarrollo, puedes aplicar gran varidad de tests para tus pipelines de CI/CD.

Una desventaja para mi es que, al vivir mucho tiempo, y por lo tanto tener demasiados commits, puede haber muchos conflictos por los cambios que una feature introduzca a dev, y que otro desarrollador en otra feature no haya bajado.

Por lo mismo de la larga duración de la rama develop, requiere de muchísima comunicación con tu equipo porque cada quien tiene su propia velocidad y estilo, y luego te encuentras que alguien ya modificó muchos archivos comunes que tu creías estables, o añadió cosas auxilieras que tú también añadiste, y entonces puede haber trabajo duplicado.

También, por lo mismo, puede que develop se desvie muchísimo de la rama principal y entras en otros conflictos al hacer el merge final.

Otro problemón es cuando salen errores en producción. Para resolver esos errores, se crean unas ramas directamente desde master llamadas "hotfix". Se resuelve el bug y se empujan a *master* de nuevo. Como te imaginarás, ahora la rama *develop* tiene que traerse también esos cambios... y con ello también cada *feature* dependiente. Esto (no tengo pruebas de esto) eleva la posibilidad de inestabilidad y conflictos en la rama develop.

### Feature branch

Otro flujo de trabajo es el llamado *feature branch workflow*. Que en esencia lo que busca es velocidad, feedback, y aislamiento entre features:

[image]

Aquí no hay una rama llamada "development" que tenga todas las features, sino que por cada feature, se crea una rama con ciertas convenciones de nombres, e.g. "ISSUE-9991", "feature-connector-bq".

Estas ramas son de corta duración y cuando se terminan de hacer la features con sus pruebas, se crea una rama remota, se corren los mismos test pero ahora en el entorno de pruebas, se levanta un PR sobre *main*, se pide feedback de gente de tu equipo (que deberían contestar rápido), y se atienden los comentarios, y luego se aprueba y hace merge a *main*.

Aquí, si tienes un bug en master, se crea un como tipo *hotfix* que sale como otra feature de branch, y se mezcla en branch de nuevo. Si te das cuenta, una feature y un bug, conviven bien porque no tienen tantas piezas móviles.

Y como estos workflows, **hay muchos otros**. En tu caso particular parece que estabas usando el de *feature branch*.

Comment: Muy buena y completa respuesta, aprecio mucho el tiempo dedicada a la misma. 'Feature branch workflow' suena mucho mejor y menos problematica. Entonces, la idea es crear un nuevo branch.o rama para agregar una nueva funcionalidad para luego hacer un commit y push directamente, es decir, la branch creada se sube al servidor para que luego otras personas la puedan ver, descargar, y probar directamente en el servidor (subdominio de prueba). Cuando dices PR a que te refieres?

Comment: No estaría mal dejar las fuentes de las imágenes.

Comment: deberias indicar de donde obtubiste la informacion; dejas la fuente oficiales y dar credito siempre es bueno.

Comment: @Mateo y ArcanisGK50, Si lo pensé, pero por flojera solo di "ctrl + v" de lo que encontré en google images. Enseguida lo pongo, Gracias por el feedback y puntuación positiva!

Comment: @Carlos, me refiero a las siglas de lo que se conoce como "Pull Request", o que también le llaman Merge Request. Osea, una petición, que se da al repositorio remoto, para que los cambios que subiste a tu rama remota, sean aplicados a otra rama remota (por lo general es a "master" o a "development").

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me acaban de decir que se utiliza 'Git-flow' (aunque me gusta mas el segundo que has mencionado), es decir, cada desarollador tiene un branch llamado 'dev-nombreDesarrollador'. Esto significa que cada dia debo cambiarme a master, bajarme los cambios y hacer lo mismo el mi branch? si me indicas los pasos, lo apreciaria

Comment: Eso no está bien! No se debe de usar el nombre del desarrollador porque no aporta información valiosa al proyecto y puede confundir muchas cosas porque, qué pasa si varios desarrolladores trabajan el la misma feature? Entonces tendría múltiples ramas que se conflictuarían entre si!

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que 1) Mantengas actualizada la rama de dev con los cambios más recientes de master, 2) Crees una rama A PARTIR DE DEV llamada "mi-feature" con el nombre de lo que te toca hacer de trabajo como, "feature-get-age-average" o con el código de tu issue como, "ISSUE-443-get-age-average" 3) cuando termines, hagas push a esa rama pero en remota, 4) Levantes un PR o MR directamente desde gitlab/github/bitbucket, 5) Marcar mi respuesta como buena si te ayudó

Comment: Desde mi experiencia, si la gente crea ramas con sus nombres es porque tanto no saben comunicarse entre ellos (timidez, miedo), y al mismo tiempo no confían en los demás, "Estos son mis cambios, y esos son tuyos, y no quiero que me toques los míos y que he echen la culpa de tocar los tuyos"

Comment: No usen sus nombres como descripción de una rama! Cada commit ya lleva el nombre y correo de quien lo hizo, Entonces, para qué ser redundante? Si quieres saber quién hizo X cosa, pueden usar `git log --author="Juan Sanchez"`. Si quieren aislar su trabajo, aíslenlo por features. Si van a tocar algo sensible a todo el team, usen el chat global del team para informarlo. Si van a hacer una utilidad común, comuníquense entre ustedes.

Comment: De lo contrario, no están usando gitflow, sino otra cosa. Y no lo están usando porque gitflow necesita ramas de "features", no ramas de "autores".

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo, tu respuesta y comentarios (y tambien los del resto de la comunidad) me han ayudado a entender casi todo. Entonces podemos afirmar que no se esta siguendo un workflow en particular sino que es un hibrido que presenta algunos errores, correcto?

Comment: Creo que se va a cambiar a otro workflow en un futuro pero no depende de mi, entonces procedo a preguntarte: teniendo en cuenta que cada desarrollador tiene su rama en local y sube directamente a master, aunque mi caso es un poco diferente, la misma rama que tengo en local, la tengo en remoto y no voy a subir nada a master branch. Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior mencionado, yo deberia cambiarme todos los dias a la rama master para hacer un pull y luego a mi rama para hacer un pull desde master (del remoto) a mi branch (dev-carlos), correcto?

Comment: Todos los días tienes que revisar el estado de tu repo con algo como `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`. Si ves que hay más commits en master, entonces te los traes tanto a dev como a tu rama local que no llamarás "dev-carlos", sino "feature-nombre-de-tu-feature". Para traertelos haz un pull de tus ramas remotas a tus ramas locales, y luego un checkout a tu rama de feature y desde ahí haz un merge con la rama local actualizada (dev o master). De nuevo revisa con `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` el estado de todas tus ramas.

Comment: Puede parecer muy engorroso, pero la idea es: tu rama de feature tiene que tener tanto TODOS los commits de "development" y también tus commits de tus avances, además que tu rama de "development" tiene que tener todos los commits de "master" además del trabajo previo de todos tus compañeros.

Comment: Si mi respuesta te sirvió para tu caso, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que a otros les pueda ayudar por si tienen tu mismo problema.

Comment: La he marcado como aceptada. Primero, muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Segundo, me gustaria pedirle ayuda, como hago un pull desde master (remoto) a mi rama local (diferente a master)?

Comment: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=bring+changes+from+remote+master+to+local+branch

Comment: he hecho exactamente lo que dice el primer resultado de tu link y me dio error. He publicado una nueva pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581285/como-actualizar-mi-rama-local-desde-el-m%c3%a1ster-remoto-en-git

Answer (score 4):

Es una pregunta bastante compleja aunque en mi opinión la respuesta mas estable es la C, yo cuando me inicié con GIT me basé en este modelo https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ que la verdad es que en caso de múltiples entornos y varios desarrolladores esta bastante bien.

Respecto al tema Merge etc... no se si tienes GitHub GitLab o algún otro controlador, pero personalmente soy fan de trabajar los merges a master desde el repositorio. Yo te recomendaría si tienes GitLab y cambios en una rama que quieres subir a Master:

1. Crear un Merge Request en GITLAB
2. Revisar los cambios y marcar las opciones de Squash Commit y Delete branch After Merge.

Si buscas un apoyo visual para tus repositorios puedes descargarte GitKraken o SourceTree.

Respecto a como actualizar todas tus ramas con los cambios del remoto, pull o  fetch from origin son lo ideal (Fetch from origin te detecta todos los cambios ocurridos en todas las ramas del proyecto pero no te los descarga hasta que hagas el pull, pero te informa de todos los cambios).

Es una pregunta que da para muchas horas discutiendo en un foro, lo mejor es que encuentres una forma que te sea relativamente cómoda pero dentro de los estándares (la C cumple con ello). La idea de todos estos modelos es ser mas o menos flexibles, así que iras evolucionando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Yo utilizo bitbucket, teniendo en cuenta esto, que recomiendas? Subir mis cambios hechos en una rama diferente a master, directamente a bitbucket y desde este proveedor proceder a realizar el merge con master?

Comment: Diría que si, mas que nada porque las herramientas externas suelen tener apoyo para los reverts, te controlan mejor los merge request que las ramas estén a la misma altura y por concentración, al final si usas siempre una herramienta solo para los merge, es mas difícil liarla que si la usas para 80 cosas distintas. Aun así, esto es un mundo, iras cogiendo tus preferencias con el tiempo, no hay una opción que sea infinitamente peor que otra, solo opciones que te sirven mejor en tu caso o peor