# ¿Como actualizar mi-rama local desde el máster remoto en Git?

Tags: git, git-pull

Actualmente estoy trabajando de la siguiente manera, sé que hay mejores.

Existe una rama local '**master**' y otra '**mi-rama**', la idea es que yo trabaje localmente en '**mi-rama**' y luego suba los cambios a 'mi-rama' remota.

Resumen: existe 'mi-rama' tanto en local como en remoto, y 'master' en local y remoto.

Yo tengo que mantener 'master' y 'mi-rama' locales actualizados con 'master' remoto y he intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
git checkout mi-rama
git fetch origin
git pull origin master
```

El objetivo era actualizar 'mi-rama' con 'master remoto', luego iba repetir el proceso pero cambiando la primera parte por: **git checkout master**

He recibido el siguiente mensaje de advertencia:

```
admin@Admins-iMac project % git pull origin master 
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa': 
From bitbucket.org:project/project
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

Me gustaría saber que ha pasado, porque ha pasado, que he hecho mal y cuáles son los siguientes pasos sin perder los cambios que he aplicado en 'mi-rama' local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error de master es porque al parecer editaste tu master local directamente e hiciste un nuevo commit sobre esa rama que no estaba en la remota.

En ese caso en particular, puedes resetear master a origin/master, y ya trabajar de esa manera. El problema de esa aproximación es que te borra los cambios que ya tengas en master y que necesitabas:

1. `git switch master`, y te mueves a tu rama master local
2. `git fetch --all`, para traerte todo el historial de cambios de tus repos remotos
3. `git reset --hard origin/master`, para cambiar el HEAD de tu rama "master" local, hacia el "master" remoto, osea el `origin/master`
4. `git switch mi-super-rama`, para comenzar a hacer las operaciones en tu rama
5. `git rebase -i master`, para hacer aplicar los cambios de mi-super-rama, sobre los de master, pero estando sobre mi-super-rama
6. (Opcional) En caso de que aparezca un archivo para editar, poner `p` o `s`, o `f` a los commits que se quieran editar, squashear, o añadir, y luego cerrar el archivo. Osea, seguir las instrucciones de lo que diga el archivo que se abra en la terminal
7. `git push -f origin mi-super-rama`, estos cambios los empujamos a nuestra rama remota

Otra opción es la de ver en qué commits difiere master local del remoto.

Para eso puedes hacer un `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`, para ver de forma colorida y grafica las diferencias entre cualquier rama. En este caso puedes copiar y pegar los hashes de los commits que tenga "master" local que no tenga "origin/master".

Ya que los copiaste, puedes hacer un git reset de master a origin/master. Luego te mueves a tu rama personal local "mi-super-rama", y haces un cherry pick:

```
git cherry-pick <commits que guarde>
```

Y así aplicas los cambios que habías tenido en master local y que ignoramos con el git reset del primer paso.

Comment: apreciaria si te unes: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142557/discussion-between-carlos-and-eftshift0

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta, es buena idea que la puntues positivamente o aceptes, esto debido a que ayudas a los demás que tengan tu mismo problema para que vean que esta respuesta tiene validez práctica

Comment: Me recomendaron hacer lo mismo pero sin rebase (cambiarlo por merge), tu opinion al respecto seria interesante de leer. Ya tienes la puntuacion :)

Comment: Merge es bueno y te crea un merge commit al que puedes darle rollback, pero te puede dejar tu historial de cambios muy inententible y sucio. Esto da igual para pequeños proyectos, pero para proyectos profesionales es bastante importante.

Comment: De hecho te sugeriría que o buscaras en este sitio o que lanzaras una publicación respecto a rebase y merge. Seguro habrán muy buenas respuestas que enriquecerán el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que tienes por lo menos un commit en `master` *local* que **no** está en la remota. Qué podría ser? Toca mirar la historia de ambas ramas: `git log master origin/master --graph --oneline` y ver qué fue lo que introdujiste en `master` que no está en `origin/master`.

Tengo ahora un par de comentarios.... Tu intención es que `master` (local) siempre está sobre `origin/master`? Si es así, pues algo acometiste en `master` (local), sin querer (asumiría), que hace que git se esté quejando porque las ramas divergieron. Podrías evitar que algo así suceda, si siempre quieres que la rama local quede sobre la remota haciendo esto, en vez de pull:

```
git fetch origin
git branch -f master origin/master
```

De esa forma, la rama `master` se va a colocar exactamente donde está la rama remota.... pero tengo otro comentario:

La forma en la que estás halando los cambios en `mi-rama` es trabajando directamente con la rama `origin/master` (y felicitaciones por eso!!!). Siendo así, para qué quieres mantener actualizada tu rama `master` local? Pregunto porque es mi *humilde* opinión que tener una rama **local** que solo va a estar apuntando a la remota no tiene mucho sentido, es preferible no tenerla y trabajar contra la remota (como ya estás haciendo).

### update

Considerando los comentarios, lo único que tienes que hacer es colocar `master` (local) donde debe. Haciendo esto tu rama `master` (local) siempre va a estar parada sobre lo que esté en la remota. SI tienes commits en `master` local que no están en la remota, van a desaparecer de la rama:

```
git fetch origin
git branch -f master origin/master
```

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! He hecho un cambio en master local el cual no era mi intención, luego he creado 'mi-rama' (local) y seguí trabajando sobre ese cambio. ¿Como hago para que mi master local sea un clon exacto de master remoto, es decir, que se descarten/eliminen esas modificaciones no intencionales que están en mi master local?

Comment: Por otro lado, quiero mi master local siempre actualizado con el master remoto porque mi intención original era crear ramas por cada funcionalidad (quiero decir que luego pensaba eliminarlas) y para crear una nueva pensaba clonar mi master local (por eso quiero que esté siempre actualizado), pero ahora no sé si voy a hacer eso o no, si puedo traerme los cambios de master remoto a 'mi-rama' local, creo que no tiene sentido tener master actualizado (como bien has dicho).

Comment: ¿Entonces ahora lo que tengo que hacer es descartar los cambios de master local y luego volver a intentar los comandos que están en mi pregunta?

Comment: A ver si entiendo bien tu 'UPDATE'. Primero crear un clon del master local (actual, o sea, el que tiene cambios que no debe tener), luego descargas y reemplazas todo desde 'master' remoto a 'master' local (en este paso, master local es una copia identica a master remoto), el ultimo paso no se si lo termino de entender (quizas porque no se bien para que se usa rebase) y, una duda, luego no borras la rama 'mala'?

Comment: Posiblemente no me explique bien, ese cambio que NO deberia estar en 'master 'local, si debe estar en 'mi-rama' local. Porque yo deberia haber siempre trabajado en una rama, pero empece en master y posteriormente empece a usar ramas, teniendo esto ultimo en cuenta, los comandos siguen siendo los mismos? especialmente el ultimo

Comment: Ok.... eso cambia todo. Si... la receta es un poco más corta. Ya la ajusto

Comment: entonces, la receta quedaria 'git checkout master' y luego los dos comandos que has puesto en 'UPDATE'?

Comment: En general, te diría que puedes eliminar la rama `master` local y solo la uses si lo necesitas para algo (muy) particular.

Comment: No, no hagas checkout de `master` porque entonces git no te va a dejar hacer el `git branch -f`.. Si hicieras el checkout de `master` para empezar, tendrías que hacer esto: `git fetch origin; git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142557/discussion-between-carlos-and-eftshift0).

Comment: Te espero en el chat

Comment: cambiarse a la rama master y luego hacer: git fetch origin; git reset --hard origin/master tiene el mismo efecto que busco?

Comment: si, tendría el mismo efecto de llevar la rama `master` local a lo que tiene (historia/contenido) `origin/master`.

Comment: `git reset --hard` va a limpiar tu árbol de trabajo y el índice de cualquier cosa que no esté acometida así que cuidado al usarlo.

Comment: Aprecia muchisimo, si te unes al chat, por favor